# wordpress. error creating content for custom templates with twentytwelve theme

Tags: wordpress

i'm using the twentytwelve theme and i have to write custom content into my example template.

I want to maintain my header content so the main structure is the following

```
header = id page, wrapper

ex.page = primary, content

footer = close wrapper, close id page
```

If i have understood correctly, if i want to insert content into the middle of my page i have to do it into my template page (that is a copy of the main page.php), that is in the middle between my header and my footer

For example i want to insert a div into which insert the loop of such category.

The problem is that it displays me nothing, like i've wrote nothing. I can only see the contents if i erase all the originary div, but it's not what i want to do, just because the only div is the page which is my container.

I can't catch what i have to do.

Can you tell me what i forgot to do?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

page.php is a "master" document. header.php, footer.php and (if it exists) sidebar.php are all imported into page.php.  Twenty Twelve also uses atomized content templates.  You may need to add your div to content-page.php, which is also imported into page.php. content-page.php is used inside the wordpress loop, and encapsulates the code that pulls in the actual article elements from the wordpress database.

If you are trying to add straight HTML to the templates, ensure that you are *not* adding code between the php brackets:

```
<?php // don't add html here ?>
<div>do add html here</div>
```

Depending upon the type of wordpress page you are trying to display, you may need to consult the [Wordpress Template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Visual_Overview) to determine the proper Wordpress naming convention for your template file (the copy of page.php).

Comment: So let me understand. page.php is my master document so my custom template will not be a copy of the page.php but a copy of the content-page.php? So i have to write my custom code into the content-page. But there are a lot of content- pages. How can i understand which interests me? Think that i have to write only static pages for this project.

Comment: content-page.php is literally, the code that pulls content into the page. It is used inside of page.php

The way that I found to learn which page templates are being used in a particular situation is to add the name of the page template in HTML to the top of every file in the wordpress template. That will tell you what template is of interest.  

Here is a good infographic that can help you understand what templates apply in a particular view. http://yoast.com/wordpress-theme-anatomy/

Comment: So, if i understood correctly, if i want to have some templates that "load" some "structures", i have to do one file for the template and one for the structure, the first is whole and the other is the part (so there are lot of "parts") and in the "whole" i have to "pass" to the get template part two variables that are i.e. content and page because my file name is content-page? So if i have for example a portfolio-content i have to pass portfolio and content?

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, everything in content-page.php can be put into page.php replacing the get_template_part function. All the 'content' pages are totally not required and can be combined into one file if you want simplicity.

In my opinion, it's easier to start from scratch when learning Wordpress rather than try and re-work something. The default wordpress themes don't lend themselves to be beginner friendly.

Comment: Yeah sure, i discovered this just in this period. Ok so if for example i have my n custom templates and i want that, for each of those templates i must have different elements i have to do n different content-pages, for example ex-pages then pass to the get etc... function the variables ex & pages? Otherwise how can i say to temp_alfa to load "content" alfa & to temp_beta to load "content" beta? or i have to use only the content-page.php and in that i have to switch different solutions depending on the id or what?

Comment: When you are using get_template_part, you just name you content page what you want. Some if your content page is named content-beta.php, it would be get_template_part('content','beta');

Comment: Check out this page, it may give a clearer understanding. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part